# How to store multi-line input into a list (python)

Tags: python, list, arr

How would you store a multi-line input into an list?

For example:

```
3
2 1
1 1 0
2 1 1
4 3 0 1 2
2 
1 2
1 3
```

How would I take that input and store it as a list like so:

```
examList = [
      [3],
      [2,1],
      [1,1,0], 
      [2,1,1], 
      [4,3,0,1,2], 
      [2],
      [1,2],
      [1,3]
]
```

How do you identify the end user input if there any no specific indicators?

Answer (score 2):

Keep calling the `input()` function until the line it reads in is empty. The use the `.split` method (no args = space as deliminator). Use a `list-comp` to convert each `string` to an `int` and append this to your `examList`.

Here's the code:

```
examList = []
i = input()
while i != '':
    examList.append([int(s) for s in i.split()])
    i = input()
```

And with your input, `examList` is:

```
[[3], [2, 1], [1, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1], [4, 3, 0, 1, 2], [2], [1, 2], [1, 3]]
```

---

The above method is for `Python3` which allows you to call `input()` and enter nothing (which is why we use this as a signal to check that we are done - `i != ''`).

However, from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.EOFError), we see that, in `Python2`, an empty entry to `input()` throws an `EOF` error. To get around this, I guess we could just make it so that the multi-line input is ended when the string such as: `END` is entered. This means that you must stop the entry with a line saying `'END'`:

```
examList = []
i = raw_input()
while i != 'END':
    examList.append([int(s) for s in i.split()])
    i = raw_input()
```

*Note that I've used `raw_input` as to not perform type conversion.*

which works the same as above.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr `Python2` is so outdated, I doubt they are using it, and a quick look over the OPs other questions shows that in fact they do use Python3

Comment: @Joelddon your code resulted in "EOFError: EOF when reading a line" when ran. How would you determine the end of the input?

Comment: @WilliamMerritt I will update the answer, you must be on Python2, am I right?

Comment: @Joelddon I'm running Python3.

Comment: @Joelddon, that code still has issues when getting the last element of the input ('1 3' in this case). I don't understand how _while i != ''_ iterates to the end of the input successfully. Still getting EOF errors.

Comment: So an individual `input()` statement reads *one line*. For multi-line inputs, we need to keep calling `input()` over and over again. However, we need to know when to stop calling this as otherwise the program would never stop multi-line inputting! So, we need a "signal" , or special input line that tells us when to break out of our infinite `while` loop. This could be *anything*. In the first snippet, I used an empty string (`''`) and in the second I used the string: `'END'`. This method definitely works and I am testing it, so I don't know what's going wrong for you. Please elaborate on errs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sys.stdin.readlines()`.

For example, start with

```
import sys
user_input = sys.stdin.readlines()
```

at this point, the value of `user_input` should be

```
['3\n', '2 1\n', '1 1 0\n', '2 1 1\n', '4 3 0 1 2\n', '2\n', '1 2\n', '1 3']
```

then, you should be able to get your desired output by performing the following processing

```
examList = []

for input_string in user_input:
   examList.append([int(value) for value in input_string.split()])
```

What we are doing here is iterating through `user_input`. For each `input_string`, we `split()` the words, convert them to `int` and put them back into a new list. Then, the new list will be added into `examList`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an effective one-liner:

```
>>> inp = '''3
2 1
1 1 0
2 1 1
4 3 0 1 2
2 
1 2
1 3'''
>>> [i.split() for i in inp.split('\n')]

[['3'], ['2', '1'], ['1', '1', '0'], ['2', '1', '1'], ['4', '3', '0', '1', '2'], ['2'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '3']]
```